# How can I blur an image on Mac?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, image-editing

How can I blur an image on MacOS? I would like to achieve this on a Mac Terminal or something simpler.

I see answers using ImageMagick PHP, and answers using ImageMagick on Windows, but that is not what I need.

Comment: You've not shown any working or troubleshooting. Also your question seems extremely vage

Comment: I'm open to making this question more specific. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This solution can be used in the Mac Terminal with imagemagick:

```
convert original.jpg -filter Gaussian -resize 50% -define filter:sigma=10.0 -resize 200% original_blur.jpg
```

Feel free to change the sigma=10.0 to change the bluriness. Increase the sigma value to make more blurry, and decrease the sigma value to make it less blurry.